# How can I run iTunes without installing Bonjour in Windows 7?

Tags: itunes, windows, bonjour

I just checked my Windows error logs and Bonjour has caused a ton of errors.  After reading about Bonjour and not needing the networking services it provides, I deleted it.  Now when I open iTunes, an error message appears saying that there is a problem and that it has to close.

Other posts ([1](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1191389), [2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2742874?tstart=0)) seem to imply that iTunes can run without Bonjour.

How can I get iTunes running on my Windows 7 machine without installing Bonjour?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what you are looking for but I have, on occasion, done a standard iTunes install and then gone into Programs and Features and uninstall Bonjour. That and Apple Software Update show up as separate items for installation.

What it then leaves behind, I am unsure of. You used to be able to run regmon and watch installs to see what it installed so you could then rip it out by the roots later. But I gather that it is no longer supported. Not sure if Process Monitor will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This article is a little stale but it worked for me awhile back...

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/the-unofficial-guide-to-installing-itunes-10-without-bloatware/2390